# How to investigate warnings in progress bar in pandas_profiling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-profiling

When using the default example for displaying a report:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(100, 5),
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
)

profile = ProfileReport(df, title='Pandas Profiling Report', html={
                        'style': {'full_width': True}})
```

the correlations heatmaps are not shown.

How can I investigate the warnings from the progress bar?

[image]

Comment: What warnings are you referring to?

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot the progress bar creates the ouput with "warnings [correlation]". This is exactly my question. Where can I see those warnings in detail

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar keeps you informed on the calculations that pandas-profiling does.

To view the output, you have several option. The easiest way to view them is by generating a HTML report:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(100, 5),
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
)

profile = ProfileReport(df, title='Pandas Profiling Report', html={
                        'style': {'full_width': True}})
profile.to_file("report.html", silent=False)
```