# Unable to display progress bar on pandas_profiling

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I wrote some code to read some data on an excel file using pandas and wanted to do some data analysis on it using pandas_profiling. However, since its taking too long, I wanted to see some sort of progress bar on how much work was done and ran profiling in minimal mode to speed up the work. I found two separate ways to display, the progress bar. One as follows: ( [Link here](http://www.lib4dev.in/info/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/49346299). In in the advanced usage section I found code for the following).

```
prof = ProfileReport(data, minimal=True, progress_bar=True)
prof.to_file(output_file='output.html')
```

Another way is as follows ( I found this in a stackoverflow post. [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60744071/how-to-investigate-warnings-in-progress-bar-in-pandas-profiling) ):

```
prof = ProfileReport(data, minimal=True, html={ 'style' : {'full_width' : True}})
prof.to_file(output_file='ouput.html')
```

However both don't seem to work. The code is taking too long to execute ( I waited for around 5 hours but to no avail). Is there a way to display a progress bar? And if possible, please suggest ways to speed up the work too. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Python 3.7 on Spyder that comes along with Ananconda (If that's of any help).

Comment: Which version of pandas-profiling are you running?

Comment: I was using pandas-profiling 1.4. Thanks to your comment I checked my version and updated it and it started working immediately. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some snooping around and a question on the comments section by Simon, I found out the problem. I was running pandas-profiling 1.4 and when I updated it to the latest one (2.8) it started worked immediately and the code produced a report with 15 seconds. So updating pandas-profiling helped.